# jcarousel auto cycle / turn

Tags: cycle, jcarousel

I used [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) for doing somemthing like that:
[Carousel with autoscrolling](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) but I could not.

I created a `custom.js` file to add all my js. And for the *jCarousel* part I used this code:

```
$(function() {

    $.fn.startCarousel = function() {
        var bodywidth = $('body').width(),
            itemwidth = $('.mycarousel li').outerWidth(true),       
            mycontwidth = bodywidth > itemwidth ? bodywidth - bodywidth%itemwidth : itemwidth,
            licount = $('.mycarousel li').size(),
            jscroll = 1;

        if(licount > mycontwidth/itemwidth){
            jscroll =  mycontwidth/itemwidth;
        } else {
            jscroll = 0;
            mycontwidth = licount * itemwidth;
        }

        $('.mycont').width(mycontwidth);

        $('.mycarousel').jcarousel({
            scroll:jscroll
        });
    };

    $(this).startCarousel();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $(this).startCarousel();
    }); 
    var carousel = $('.mycarousel');
    $(carousel).jcarousel({
        scroll:1,
        wrap: 'circular'
    });

    carousel.touchwipe({
        wipeLeft: function() {
            carousel.jcarousel('next');
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
            carousel.jcarousel('prev');
        }
    });

});
```

I also tried:

```
var carousel = $('.mycarousel');
$(carousel).jcarousel({
    auto:2,
    scroll:1,
    wrap: 'last'
});
```

or `wrap: 'circular'` but that did not work as well.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>


$(function() {
    $("#carouselContainerIDhere").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#carouselContainerIDhere .next",
        btnPrev: "#carouselContainerIDhere .prev",
        speed: 500,
        auto: boo
    });    
});
var boo = "true";
if($content.boo.value)
    boo = $content.boo.value;
</script>
```